# Function not working if src is a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

With this HTML the function `myFunc()` can be executed. `https://myurl.de/myjs.js` has the function `myFunc` in it.

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://myurl.de/myjs.js"></script>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   myFunc();
  </script>
 </body>
</head>
```

But with the second HTML I get an Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined`.

`https://myurl.de/settingsFile.js` is a file that includes this url in a `var`: `https://myurl.de/myjs.js` so basically `SettingsFile.UrlToMyJS` is this `https://myurl.de/myjs.js`

```
<head>
 <script src="https://myurl.de/settingsFile.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" id="myid"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('myid').src = SettingsFile.UrlToMyJS;
   myFunc();
  </script>
 </body>
```

When I `console.log(document.getElementById('myid'))` this is the output:

`<script type="text/javascript" id="myid" src="https://myurl.de/myjs.js></script>` which is correct. It looks exactly like the script in the head of the first html (with the difference that it has the `id="myid"`).

Yet it does not work. Why and how can I fix it?

settingsFile.js:

```
var defaultURL = 'https://myurl.de/';
var SettingsFile = {
UrlToMyJS : defaultURL + 'myjs.js',
}
```

Comment: Look at your body in a mirror : the head is above it, not around :)

Comment: Could you please post the actual content of `settingsFile.js` instead of _describing_ it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh you right, sorry. These mistakes only exist in my thread. The real files don't have those small mistakes. I corrected them.

Comment: @JeremyThille Hi, I just edited my thread and added the settingsFile.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that you can't add a `src` to a `script` element that's **already** in the DOM — or rather, doing so doesn't do anything. The `script` element has *already* been processed.

Instead, create it and then append it:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.onload = function() {
    myFunc();
};
script.src = SettingsFile.UrlToMyJS;
document.head.appendChild(script);
// If you need to support IE8, use the following instead of the previous line:
//document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

That waits for the script to load, then calls `myFunc` (which should exist by then).

Also note that as I and Jeremy pointed out in the comments, `body` doesn't go *in* `head`, it goes after. It's also generally best to put `script` tags at the end of `body` (if you're not using `async` or `defer` attributes on them or `type="module"`). So in all, something like:

```
<head>
    <!-- head stuff here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- content here -->
    <script src="https://myurl.de/settingsFile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = function() {
        myFunc();
    };
    script.src = SettingsFile.UrlToMyJS;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    // If you need to support IE8, use the following instead of the previous line:
    //document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    </script>
</body>
```

Another option is to use `document.write`. This sort of thing may be the last at-least-partially appropriate use of `document.write` during the main parsing of the page:

```
<head>
    <!-- head stuff here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- content here -->
    <script src="https://myurl.de/settingsFile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script src="' + SettingsFile.UrlToMyJS + '"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script>
    myFunc();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a element and then appending it to your title

For Example (script code) :

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "YOUR_SCRIPT_SRC_HERE";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Here I am creating a new tag in html and then appending it to the head of your html. Even as T.J. Crowder mentioned in the comment try removing your `body` from the `head`

Comment: Actually, contrary to my deleted comment, there **is** an `append` now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: Note that if the OP just puts the call to `myFunc();` immediately after the above, it won't work -- you have to wait for the script to load.